# Retrieving specific dictionary value - Python

Tags: python, dictionary

Sorry guys this is a very newbie question. I currently have the following code

```
import googlemaps
import json as js
from datetime import datetime

gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key=googleapikey)
my_distance = gmaps.distance_matrix('350 5th Ave, New York, NY 10118',
                                '4 Pennsylvania Plaza, New York, NY 10001')
print(my_distance)
```

the print out is the the following

> {'status': 'OK', 'rows': [{'elements': [{'distance': {'value': 876, 'text':     '0.9 km'}, 'duration': {'value': 324, 'text': '5 mins'}, 'status': 'OK'}]}],      'destination_addresses': ['4 Pennsylvania Plaza, New York, NY 10001, USA'], 'origin_addresses': ['350 5th Ave, New York, NY 10118, USA']}

I ultimately want to extract the result 0.9km. How do I do that?

I have tried using

```
print(my_distance['rows'])
```

and that only gives me

> [{'elements': [{'status': 'OK', 'distance': {'value': 876, 'text': '0.9 km'}, 'duration': {'value': 324, 'text': '5 mins'}}]}]

```
print(my_distance['rows']['elements']['distance'])
```

I then get an error

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

any help would be much appreciated thanks!

Comment: _rows_ and _elements_ are a lists, thus you need to specify index of record you're interested in: `print(my_distance['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance'])`

Comment: `print(my_distance['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'])`

Comment: I see that makes a lot of sense thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`elements` and `rows` is are list of dictionaries, not a dictionary themselves.  Access them like this:

```
print(my_distance['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance'])
```

Comment: Not only `elements` is

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> mydict = {'status': 'OK', 'rows': [{'elements': [{'distance': {'value': 876, 'text': '0.9 km'}, 'duration': {'value': 324, 'text': '5 mins'}, 'status': 'OK'}]}], 'destination_addresses': ['4 Pennsylvania Plaza, New York, NY 10001, USA'], 'origin_addresses': ['350 5th Ave, New York, NY 10118, USA']}
>>> mydict['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text']
    '0.9 km'
```

dictionary is {key:value}, list in python is `[elementA, elmentB]`,  therefore for `dict2 = {key:[{key:value}]}`  you have to use dict2['key'][0] to get the inner `{key:value}`